# Add site to trusted sites through GPO

Tags: group-policy

I need to add a site to trusted sites on all computers in my domain. I can do it with the "site to zone assignment list", however when I do, it locks trusted sites on the client computer "this setting is managed by your administrator".
What I need is a way to add the site, make it persistant, and not affects the users ability to add trusted sites of thier own. (It's a development enviroment, sites are created and tested regularly, they need that ability.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use logon scripts you could push a .reg file that has the trusted sites in there...that way you're not using the GPO to "take control".

Something similar is described here: http://nefaria.com/2009/10/adding-trusted-sites-for-ie-via-the-registry/

Also, if you don't want to replace what a user has already entered, there is a syntax to "append" data to a registry key...that way you can just add a global list but not wipe out individual additions already made by a user.

Here is some registry editing syntax : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371168%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using logon scripts... GPO is so much cleaner. Can I stealth the script so its transparent to the user?

Comment: You could use VB instead of a batch file and make the script invisible to the user...if you're more proficient with batch files you can use GPO to Run Legacy Logon Scripts Hidden.

Comment: Your statement that GPO is cleaner than Logon scripts makes me think that you don't really understand either one. A Logon script can and should be configured in a GPO, not on the properties of the user account. By default Logon scripts called from a GPO run hidden.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have WinNT6 clients (Vista / Win7 / Win8), use a Group Policy preference setting to add the REG entry.  Preference settings do not restrict the user's UI.  Job done.

See [Registry Extension TechNet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771589.aspx) for more info.